# finding partial sum of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Calculate $S_{3},S_{4},S_{5}$ in $$S=\sum^{\infty}_{k=3}\bigg(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}\bigg)$$
>
> Where $S_{r}$ is the partial sum using the first $r$ values of $n$

What i try

$$S_{3}=t_{1}+t_{2}+t_{3}$$

Where $$t_{k}=\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}$$

And given $$S=\sum_{k\geq 3}t_{k}$$

Here $t_{1}=t_{2}=0$ and $\displaystyle t_{3}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{20}$

So $$S_{3}=\frac{1}{20}$$

And $$S_{4}=t_{1}+t_{2}+t_{3}+t_{4}=0+0+\frac{1}{20}+t_{4}$$

Where $$t_{4}=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{30}$$

Is my process is right, if not then how do i find partial sum $S_{3},S_{4},S_{5}$.Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to add fractions?

Comment: Yes MathematicsStudent1122

Comment: For any $n$ we have $S_n=\frac1  4 -\frac 1 {n+2}$.

Comment: This is just adding 3,4 or 5 numbers. Am i missing something?

Comment: You have started off correctly, yes.

Comment: Thanks Professor Kavi Rama murthy.

Comment: Thanks Greg Martin...